# JavaScript - How to hide errors on Form Validation

Tags: javascript, validation

How do I hide the error(s) messages and the red border when a user corrects their errors on my form? At the moment it will keep showing the error(s) until the page is refreshed or submitted.

```
function checkForm() {
            var valid = true;

            if (!retext.test(document.myform.textfield.value)) {
                document.myform.textfield.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Invalid text.";
                document.getElementById("text").style.display = "block";
                valid = false;
            }

            if (!re.test(document.myform.email.value)) {
                document.myform.email.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
                document.getElementById("emailwarn").innerHTML = "Invalid email.";
                document.getElementById("emailwarn").style.display = "block";
                valid = false;
            }

            if (!retel.test(document.myform.tel.value)) {
                document.myform.tel.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
                document.getElementById("telwarn").innerHTML = "Invalid telephone number.";
                document.getElementById("telwarn").style.display = "block";
                valid = false;
            }

            return valid;
        }
```

I really have no idea on how to do this.

Comment: What you want exactly ? Even wrong data entered and the border will be red color but it should not stop you to go next (process the page).

Comment: @JDeveloper it will if `checkForm()` is used as the condition on preventDefault of the forms submit event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `checkForm` function is called each time the form is amended you can include *else* clauses to reset the style and visible state of the warnings

```
function checkForm() {
    var valid = true;

    if (!retext.test(document.myform.textfield.value)) {
        document.myform.textfield.border = "3.5px solid red";
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Invalid text.";
        document.getElementById("text").style.display = "block";
        valid = false;
    } else {
        document.myform.textfield.border = 0;
        document.getElementById("text").style.display = "none";
    }

    if (!re.test(document.myform.email.value)) {
        document.myform.email.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
        document.getElementById("emailwarn").innerHTML = "Invalid email.";
        document.getElementById("emailwarn").style.display = "block";
        valid = false;
    } else {
        document.myform.email.border = 0;
        document.getElementById("emailwarn").style.display = "none";
    }

    if (!retel.test(document.myform.tel.value)) {
        document.myform.tel.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
        document.getElementById("telwarn").innerHTML = "Invalid telephone number.";
        document.getElementById("telwarn").style.display = "block";
        valid = false;
    } else {
        document.myform.tel.border = 0;
        document.getElementById("telwarn").style.display = "none";
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: At the moment I have the function called using the `<form>... onsubmit="return checkForm()">`. How do I call the function when the form is being amended?

Comment: I guess you would do something like this - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2eaYL/2/)

Comment: Thank you, at the moment I'm using both `onsubmit` and `onchange`. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just add code which clears up the error messages at the beginning of your `checkForm()` function.

In your current code if error messages had been set once they have no chance to be changed on the correct input.

For example,

```
function clearErrors() {
  document.getElementById("text").style.display      = "none";
  document.getElementById("emailwarn").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("telwarn").style.display   = "none";
}

function checkForm() {      
  var valid = true;

  clearErrors();

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first it would be better to seperate javascript and CSS styles, by applying classes:

```
input.error {
  border: 3.5px solid red;
}
```

To apply the style:

```
document.myform.textfield.classList.add("error");
```

To remove the style:

```
document.myform.textfield.classList.remove("error");
```

To hide the warn element use:

```
document.getElementById("telwarn").style.display = "none";
```

Beware that [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) does not work with ie < 10